# Adding a row to an existing Pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the below pivot table:

```
  Fruit |                 |  apple |   orange  |   banana  
 Market |   # num bracket |        |           |           
:-----------------------------------------------------------:    
 X      |   100           |   1.2  |   1.0     |     NaN     
 Y      |   50            |   2.0  |   3.5     |     NaN    
 Y      |   100           |   NaN  |   3.6     |     NaN    
 Z      |   50            |   NaN  |     NaN   |     1.6    
 Z      |   100           |   NaN  |     NaN   |     1.3
```

I want to add in the below row at the bottom

```
Fruit   |  apple |  orange  |   banana  
Price   |  3.5   | 1.2      |  2
```

So the new table looks like the below

```
 Fruit  |      x          |  apple |   orange  |   banana  
 Market |   # num bracket |        |           |           
:-----------------------------------------------------------:    
 X      |   100           |   1.2  |   1.0     |     NaN     
 Y      |   50            |   2.0  |   3.5     |     NaN    
 Y      |   100           |   NaN  |   3.6     |     NaN    
 Z      |   50            |   NaN  |     NaN   |     1.6    
 Z      |   100           |   NaN  |     NaN   |     1.3   
 Price  |                 |  3.5   | 1.2      |      2
```

Does any one have a quick in easy recommendation on how to do this?

Comment: print(df.columnsIndex(['apple', 'orange', 'banana', ], dtype='object', name='Fruit')

Comment: df.index  = MultiIndex(levels=[['X', 'Y', ''], [50, 100]],
           names=['Fruit Market', '# num bracket'])

Comment: Thank you very much, only last question. For one row DataFrame what is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: df.index = MultiIndex(levels=[['X', 'Y', 'Z'], [50, 100]], names=['Fruit Market', '# num bracket']) - sorry adapting an example a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'Fruit Market':'Price',
                              'apple':3.5,
                              'orange':1.2
                              'banana':2}],
                       columns=['Fruit Market','x','apple','orange','banana'])

pd.concat([df, temp_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: For anyone using cudf instead of pd, the `data` argument should be passed the raw dict rather than a list containing a dict.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna make sure we have the same table structure, so if the out put for:

```
your_pivot_table.loc[('Z', 100)]
```

is

```
apple   NaN
orange  NaN
banana  1.3
Name: (Z, 100), dtype: float64
```

Then, the solution is creating a new series with same index as the output above, but with different values.

So instead of `[NaN, NaN, 1.3]`, we need a series with values `[3.5, 1.2, 2]` but with same index.

Here are my code to produce that series:

```
pd.Series([3.5, 1.2, 2], index = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'])
```

The output for it is:

```
apple   3.5
orange  1.3
banana  2
dtype: float64
```

The last step is inserting that new series into pivot table, using `.loc`, so we will insert our new series to `your_pivot_table` using index `('Price', '')`, so the final code would looked like this:

```
your_pivot_table.loc[('Price', '')] = pd.Series([3.5, 1.2, 2], index = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'])
```